# Serve static file using App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, static-html

I created an App Engine application. Till now, I only have a few HTML files to serve. What can I do to make App Engine serve the index.html file whenever someone visits http://example.appengine.com/ ?

Currently, my app.yaml file looks like this:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /
  static_dir: static_files
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should do what you need:

https://gist.github.com/873098

Explanation: In App Engine Python it's possible to use regular expressions as URL handlers in `app.yaml` and redirect all URLs to a hierarchy of static files.

Example `app.yaml`:

```
application: your-app-name-here
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.txt)

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xml)

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# index files
- url: /(.+)/
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html

# redirect to 'url + /index.html' url.
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static/redirector.html
  upload: static/redirector.html

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

In order to handle requests to URLs that don't end with a recognized type (`.html`, `.png`, etc.) or `/` you need to redirect those requests to `URL + /` so the `index.html` for that directory is served. I don't know of a way to do this inside the `app.yaml`, so I added a javascript redirector.  This could also be done with a tiny python handler.

`redirector.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      self.location=self.location + "/";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although this might have worked for the OP, but there are two correct, very concise and exact answers here, compared to which this is incorrect. This is not how this should be done.

Comment: Nice explanation on https://gusclass.com/blog/2013/09/27/dead-simple-app-engine-static-hosting/

Comment: I faced a problem with this approach and posted a question on stack overflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631414/how-can-i-use-bucket-storage-to-serve-static-files-on-google-flex-app-engine-env

The requests for static files were hitting my nodejs servers (which means they are not using a CDN).

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to map `/` to `index.html`:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  upload: folderpath/index.html
  static_files: folderpath/index.html
```

---

the `url:` will match on a path and supports regex.

```
- url: /images
  static_dir: static_files/images
```

So if your image file is stored at `static_files/images/picture.jpg` use this:

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" />
```

Comment: If `index.html` is in your root, omit `folderpath/`.

Comment: Now I am able to access index.html but the images stored in static_files/images are not accessible.

Comment: Be careful, the order of the handlers matter!

Answer (score 9):

It could be done using (app.yaml):

```
handlers:
- url: /appurl
  script: myapp.app

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: staticdir/\1
  upload: staticdir/(.*)

- url: /
  static_files: staticdir/index.html
  upload: staticdir/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is app.yaml for how I got a site generated by Jekyll to work:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true


handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: _site/index.html
  upload: _site/index.html

- url: /assets
  static_dir: _site/assets



  # index files
- url: /(.+)/
  static_files: _site/\1/index.html
  upload: _site/(.+)/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: _site/\1
  upload: _site/(.*)

- url: /.*
  static_dir: _site
```

Answer (score 1):

In WEB-INF/web.xml put:

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: He's using Python not Java

Comment: This is Java example, It would be nice if explain it in full.