# ImportError - No module named main in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, importerror

In my Google App Engine app, I'm getting the error

> ImportError: No module named main

when going to the URL `/foo`.  All the files in my app are in the parent directory.

Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
application: foobar
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:

- url: /foo.*
  script: main.application

- url: /
  static_files: index.html

- url: /(.*\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|png|ico))
  static_files: \1
  upload: .*
  expiration: "1d"
```

Here is my `main.py`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class Handler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello world!') 

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/foo', Handler)],
                                         debug=False)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the same error when I change `main.application` to `main.py` or just `main`.  Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers) says,

> Static files cannot be the same as application code files. If a static
>   file path matches a path to a script used in a dynamic handler, the
>   script will not be available to the dynamic handler.

In my case, the problem was that the line

```
upload: .*
```

matched all files in my parent directory, including main.py.  This meant that main.py was not available to the dynamic handler.  The fix was to change this line to only recognize the same files that this rule's URL line recognized:

```
upload: .*\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|png|ico)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your configuration is OK - only for a small misstep in the `main.py`: you need an access of the `application` name from the `main` module, thus the config is: `main.application`. This change should do the trick:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/foo', Handler)],
                                     debug=False)
def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Don't worry - the `application` object will not *run* on creation, nor on import from this module, it will run only on explicit all such as `.run_wsgi_app` or in google's internal architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at getting started with python27. You mixing CGI and WSGI. You have to use webapp2 here.

Your WSGI main.py :

```
import webapp2

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello World!')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/foo', Handler),
], debug=True)
```

See also this blog post about CGI and WSGI : http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

Comment: Thanks, I should be using webapp2.  However, it still doesn't work.  The [hello world example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) works fine; the problem seems to happen when the python script is not the main request handler (i.e. only for `/foo.*`)

Comment: Please explain. What do you mean with : "when the python script is not the main request handler"

Comment: As in, it only handles URLs starting with `/foo`, not the base URL `/`.

Comment: But you did not create a handler for '/', and what about : ImportError: No module named main? Is this problem solved.

Comment: index.html is the handler for `/`. The problem is not solved.

Comment: The index.html yaml config for / will not work : have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609000/serve-static-file-using-app-engine

Comment: That question seems to apply only when files are in sub-directories.  All my files are in the same directory.

Comment: Compare your site root / config to the one in the answer.

Comment: Mine looks the same, except there's no sub-directory for static files.  What are you getting at?

Comment: # site root
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html # THIS ONE IS MISSING

Comment: Right, sorry, I already put that back in at some point, and it doesn't seem to affect anything.  I think the problem is actually related to ["Static files cannot be the same as application code files. If a static file path matches a path to a script used in a dynamic handler, the script will not be available to the dynamic handler."](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)  However, I can't see how `main.py` matches the static request handlers.