# Is there a simple way to share static website with complex directory structures on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

Im trying to get a static website structure to work on on google app engine. The site is fetched with -wget from a CMS that uses clean urls.

```
- www/
  - index.html
  - page-1/
     - index.html
     - subpage-1/
         - index.html
         - subsubpage-1
             - index.html
    - page-2/
     - index.html
  - somestaticstuff/-
     - style.css
     - image.jpg
     - ...
```

The idea would be to get the following "clean url" structure to work properly.

- myapp.domain.com/ -> www/index.html
- myapp.domain.com/page-1/subpage-1/ -> www/page-1/subpage-1/index.html

Basicly route all trafic to public www/ folder.
If any folder has index.html show it.
Most common files shoud all be available from any directory path.

Been playing around with different yaml configurations from different tutorials but they only seem show how to do it on basic structures where you know how your site is structured.
Do i realy have to describe every single subfolder in the app.yaml one by one 
as static_folder or is there a simpler way to describe this  "reclusive" in the app.yaml.

I apologize if this question is noobish, im running out of time learning how this works and google doesn't seem to be my friend on this one.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609000/serve-static-file-using-app-engine

Comment: I had not but this worked perfectly for me. Many thanks!