# CSS not loading on gcloud app engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud

So, I'm trying to host a website on the google cloud app engine, but css and other static files are not showing up.
Here is the relevant directory structure:

```
myapp
  -app.yaml
  -manage.py
  subapp
    -apps.py
    -models.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
    static
      -style.css
```

And the relevant portion of app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex 
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: .*
  script: myapp.wsgi.application
```

I would expect that when I go to `https://myapp.appspot.com/static/style.css`, they see the style.css file, but instead I get the 404 page not found error, and I see that gcloud compares the 'static/style.css' against the list of urls found in urls.py instead of the static directory specified in app.yaml.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use bucket storage to serve static files on google flex/app engine environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631414/how-can-i-use-bucket-storage-to-serve-static-files-on-google-flex-app-engine-env)

Comment: I suspect that your project root is set to `myapp` whereas the `static` is one directory below. Have you tried `static_dir: subapp/static` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, static handlers do not work on the flexible environment. You should just serve your CSS the way you normally would from your python application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /static/style.css
  static_files: static/style.css
  upload: static/style.css
```