# Use of gcloud app deploy using sdk always results in error

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am using the following app.yaml.  I am trying to deploy my angular app. Tried to use 3 different variants of the sdk but everytime it throws an error. - 218 -201- 215

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

threadsafe: true


automatic_scaling:
 min_num_instances: 1
 max_num_instances: 10
 cool_down_period_sec: 120 # default value

skip_files:

- ^(.*\/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*\/)?.*\.py$
- ^(.*\/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^.git(.*\/)?
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$

- ^(.*)?\/?src[\/]?(?:(.*)?[\/]?)$
- ^[\.]?ssl(.*[\/]?)?$
- ^[\.]?idea(.*[\/]?)?$ 
- ^[\.]?e2e(.*[\/]?)?$


handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  application_readable: true
- url: /
  static_dir: dist
  application_readable: true
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|json|woff2|svg|ttf|eot|woff))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|json|woff2|svg|ttf|eot|woff)$
  application_readable: true
```

But I am always ending up with the error
      gcloud components update --version 185.0.0
      ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): unsupported operand type(s) for 
      +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

```
  If you would like to report this issue, please run the following 
  command:
  gcloud feedback

  To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following 
  command:
   gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Could someone guide me with this?
Note: I was able to deploy successfully a couple of days ago with the version - 201.

Comment: So you see the error at `gcloud components update` (i.e. updating the SDK)? If so the GAE/app info is rather irrelevant, maybe even misleading, focus only on the SDK itself. At which version is it now? Which OS?

Comment: Side note: serving static files via `handlers` in `app.yaml` only works in standard env, not in flex, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631414/how-can-i-use-bucket-storage-to-serve-static-files-on-google-flex-app-engine-env/41636565#41636565

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I will remove the handlers in app.yaml and try it out

Comment: Its still giving me the same error. I removed the handlers, skip_files section but still results in the same error

Comment: The handlers aren't related. You still didn't clarify if the error shows at app deployment or at sdk update time. Can you include the actual log, command included?

Comment: Yeah sure @DanCornilescu. The error occured at the time of deployment . Here are the error logs in the link. The complete details are there

Comment: Here is the link -  [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/552]

Comment: I was able to deploy it succesfully on last thursday and here is the app.yaml file. Its the same except that I am currently trying with a Dockerfile and previously I was not. This is the only change that I made **runtime: python27
service: adtech-ui**

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure as to why . I am everybit confused as well. I removed all the comments I had for "skip_files" section and then it allowed me deploy without any errors

```
api_version: 1
runtime: python
env: flex
threadsafe: yes

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 120
  timeout_sec: 40
  failure_threshold: 5
  success_threshold: 5
  app_start_timeout_sec: 1500




skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$ 
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
- ^node_modules/(.*/)?
- ^src/(.*/)?


handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist
```