# Google App Engile , Node JS, not work serving javascript static files

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-app-engine

When I put into addressbar the css, images work but my javascript files not work.

Eg:

https://(...).appspot.com/build/teste.css (work)
https://(...).appspot.com/build/teste.js (404 error - The requested URL /build/mycomponent.js was not found on this server.)

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10


handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  expiration: '10s'

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
  expiration: '10s'

- url: /build
  static_dir: static/build
  expiration: '10s'

- url: /assets
  static_dir: static/assets
  expiration: '10s'

- url: /static
  static_dir: static/.*
  expiration: '10s'

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

My structury folder is:

```
/static
   /css 
      / *.css(work)
   /images 
      / *.png|jpg (work)
   /assets
      / *.js (not work - 404 in log view)
   /build
      / test.css (work)
      / test.js (not work - 404 in log view)
```

My index.ts file is:

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as ejs from "ejs";


const VERSION : string = "1.0.6"; 
const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 8080;
const app = express();



app.use(express.static('static'));
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.engine("html", ejs.renderFile);
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");


app.use(function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server version ${VERSION}`);
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

PS: satic_files have the same problems. I tried :

```
- url: /build/(.+)
  static_files: static/build/\1
  upload: static/build/(.*)

- url: /build/.*
  static_dir: static/build
```

Comment: Hi, you might take a look into this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609000/serve-static-file-using-app-engine).
It talks about the handlers and there is an example with javascript content.
` url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)`

Comment: The problem using static_files or static_dir is the same, only files non javascrupt  are accept. I tried 
- url: /build/(.*)
  static_files: static/build/\1
  upload: static/build/(.*)

- url: /build/.*
  static_dir: static/build

Comment: Using url: /build/(.+) not work too

Comment: Have you tried without /build? just https://(...).appspot.com/teste.js 
I have performed an example, I have the following structure:

-app.yaml
-static/
----example.js

I've set this handlers in the yaml file:

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

When I access to js resources I do: https://(...).appspot.com/example.js and it works. If I try with /static/example.js this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the request without /build? just https://(...).appspot.com/teste.js

I have performed an example, I have the following structure:

`-app.yaml
-static/
----example.js`

I've set this handlers in the yaml file:

`- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)`

When I access to js resources I do: https://(...).appspot.com/example.js and it works. If I try with /static/example.js this does not work.

I have tried with a similar structure as yours:

`-app.yaml
-static/
----assets/
--------example.js`

With this handlers:

`handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/.*
  expiration: '10s'
- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/assets/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)`

Tried: https://(...).appspot.com/example.js > works
Tried: https://(...).appspot.com/assets/example.js > Does not work

I have followed [this github](https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098)

Comment: In your example not work for me, because havent the catch 301 error.